# How I can make the program keep go next line after complete on if statement

Tags: c++

im trying to write a code but for some reason the program is stuck in a loop of the if statements

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
int main()
{
    double i = 0;
    double u = 0;
    cout << "Enter one numbers:\n";
    while (cin >> i)
        if (i > u)
        {
            cout << "the largest number is: " << i << '\n'
            << "the smallest number is " << u << "\n";
}
        else if (i < u) {
            cout << "the largest number is " << u << '\n'
                << "the smallest number is " << i << "\n";
        }
        else if (i == u) {
            cout << "The numbers are equal\n";
        }
        cout << "blabla\n";
        keep_window_open();

}
```

So my purpose is that after it checks the "if else" even is some of them true or not I need it to performe  `cout << "blabla\n";`
the code is not finished, I just need to understand how to make it jump to another line so I will be able to keep write the continue.

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) page. You should also try to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). `std_lib_facilities.h` is not a standard C++ header.

Comment: Read more a good C++ programming book. Then compile your code with all warnings & debug info (e.g. with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). **Use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Ron  It is a header used in a book of Stroustrup.

Comment: Under which condition do you want your loop to continue? Or, asking the same differently, under which condition do you want the loop to stop?

Comment: @Bar Glick The program outputs  blabla independent on any condition in the  if-else statements.

Comment: Currently the if-construct is the only thing inside your loop. Is that intended? If not you need to open a pair of `{}` right after the `while(...)` and close it after the last part you want in your loop. That, as far as I understand, is the `cout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right, and you just need to print `"blabla\n"` every time inside the `while` loop, then you only need to put curly braces around, like this:

```
while (cin >> i) {
    if (i > u) { ... }
    else if (i < u) { ... }
    ...
    cout << "blabla\n";
}
```

In general, you better write curly braces everywhere, because avoiding them saves you a second today but can steal an hour several months later, just in case you ever need to add something inside.

Note that you can also use `goto` construction to pass the execution of a program from any point to any other point, but you better don't use it because it is complex both to write and read.

If instead you just wanted to get one integer, then you should have used `cin >> i;` in place of your `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is either not printing "blabla" while in the loop or not exiting the loop. For the latter see the answer by Ron.

For printing "blabla" while in the loop you need to make a block of the statements which you want executed in your loop. I.e. open a pair of `{}` right after the while and close it after the last statement you want inside the loop.

I have minimally edited your code to demonstrate the block:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
int main()
{
    double i = 0;
    double u = 0;
    cout << "Enter one numbers:\n";
    while (cin >> i)
    { // starting the block of looped statements
        if (i > u)
        {
            cout << "the largest number is: " << i << '\n'
            << "the smallest number is " << u << "\n";
        }
        else if (i < u) {
            cout << "the largest number is " << u << '\n'
                << "the smallest number is " << i << "\n";
        }
        else if (i == u) {
            cout << "The numbers are equal\n";
        }
        cout << "blabla\n";
    } // end the block of looped statements,

    // guessing that this is NOT supposed to be inside the loop
    keep_window_open();
}
```